# Truffle Object Keeps Changing to Undefined When I Try To Play With Data With React

Tags: truffle, react, drizzle

The question is in the title.  I have a React Component that displays the appropriate data when I do it in a very specific way, but breaks when I try to play with the data.

```
    state = { dataKey: "1", listAllCompanies: null};

    componentDidMount() {
        const {drizzle, drizzleState } = this.props;
        const contract = drizzle.contracts.PriorIncidents;

        const dataKey = contract.methods["listAllCompanies"].cacheCall();
        this.setState({dataKey})
    }
    render() {
        const {PriorIncidents} = this.props.drizzleState.contracts;
        const listAllCompanies = PriorIncidents.listAllCompanies[this.state.dataKey];

        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                  <h1> List the Companies </h1>
                  <p>Stored companies: {listAllCompanies && listAllCompanies.value}</p>
                  </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

That's the code when it works.  Specifically, it displays the mock data that I have on the chain.  However, if I try to modify anything, it breaks and tells me that `listAllCompanies` is undefined and I don't understand it.  Even if I try a call to `console.log(listAllCompanies)` or `console.log(listAllCompanies.values)` or if I remove the `listAllCompanies` in the jsx display, leaving `{listAllCompanies.value}` it tells me that `listAllCompanies` is now undefined.

Comment: I have messed with the state variable, as well.  It has no bearing on the issue.

I am almost positive it is related to listAllCompanies being a promise.  But I don't know how to make it resolve- when I try to use then, it says then is not a function.

Comment: I fixed it by adding an if-loop.  It's kind of a band-aid, and if anyone can help me understand why it worked, please help.

Comment: I'd guess that it is because drizzle doesn't have the data yet so it returns undefined. It should update your component when data becomes available though.